# Number of operations for Elgamal cryptosystem

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption, complexity, decryption

In page 408 of Hoffstein, Piper, and Silverman's Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography, it says

> "Roughly speaking, in order to achieve $k$ bits of security,
>   encryption and decryption for Elgamal, RSA, and ECC, requires
>   $\mathcal{O}(k^3)$ operations, while encryption and decryption for
>   lattice-based systems requires only $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$ operations".

Why does Elgamal encryption and decryption require $\mathcal{O}(k^3)$ operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Roughly speaking, in order to achieve $k$ bits of security, encryption and decryption for Elgamal, RSA, and ECC, require $\mathcal{O}(k^3)$ operations, while encryption and decryption for lattice-based systems require only $\mathcal{O}(k^2)$ operations.

That quote uses "$k$ bits of security" where there should be "a security parameters of $k$ bits" or "key size of $k$ bits". In particular, having RSA and ECC together can only mean that a confusion is made between security in bits (that I now note $b$) and key size $k$. As an aside, the quote uses $\mathcal{O}$ where formally there should be $\Theta$ or $\Omega$, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) for the difference. That's a common, I do it often!

Let's independently derive the cost counted as instructions on standard computers with fixed-width word (as customary), for $b$-bit security meaning $\Theta(2^b)$ work for an attacker to break the system,

Consider RSA with $k$-bit public modulus, and ElGamal as originally formulated, that is the [group $\Bbb Z_p^*$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) with $p$ a $k$-bit public prime and a generator for all or most of the group. The cost of the private-key operation is dominated by $\Theta(k)$ modular multiplications. Each of these has costs $\Theta(k^2)$ work using common algorithms, $\Theta(k^{\approx1.6})$ for large parameters with [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), $\Theta(k^{\approx1.5})$ for huge parameters with [Toom-Cook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication), $\Theta(k\log k)$ in theory only. Ignoring anything better than Toom-Cook, we get $\Theta(k^3)$ to $\Theta(k^{2.5})$ work. For RSA, subtract $1$ from the exponent for public-key use (encryption, signature verification) and fixed public exponent.

The two algorithms considered are vulnerable to [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), with heuristic cost $L_{(2^k)}\left[1/3,\sqrt[3]{64/9}\,\right]$ in [L-notation](http://L-notation). Assuming this remains the best attack, and keeping only the first parameter in the interest of simplicity and a little safety margin (from the standpoint of the legitimate user), we have like $\Theta(k^{1/3})$-bit security.

At $b$-bit security, the work for ElGamal as originally formulated, and RSA signature/decryption, thus comes out roughly as $\Theta(b^9)$ to $\Theta(b^{7.5})$.